# How can different ion channels of the same type have different cell responses?

Tags: neuroscience, receptor, memory, neuroplasticity

The NMDA receptor is an ion channel and contributes to synaptic plasticity and memory. It is said that calcium ion flux through the receptor is critical for this mechanism. However, there are other ion channels that let calcium ions into the cell, how come they don't contribute to synaptic plasticity (to my knowledge)?

Comment: Can you please add references?

Comment: It is not just an ion channel. The name itself suggests that it is a receptor i.e. it responds to a ligand. Perhaps you can read a tiny bit more about NMDA receptor and the answer would become obvious.

Comment: cross posted to https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/21753/how-can-different-ion-channels-of-the-same-type-have-different-cell-responses although it might get a more detailed answer here